# Retrieving values from a Map from an Elixir script

Tags: dictionary, elixir, elixir-iex

If I write a simple Map in Elixir, for example:

```elixir
person = %{ :name => "Bob", :age => 45}
```

and I save it as a script, for example

```elixir
script.exs
```

How do I retrieve Bob's age after I compile the script with

`elixir script.exs` ?

Or, even better:

```elixir
iex script.exs
```

If I then write `person[:age]`

It gives me an error:

```elixir
** (CompileError) iex:1: undefined function person/0
```

Isn't it possible to use Maps like this in Elixir?

Comment: Probably not the most fastest solution but you can implement a module with a function that returns the required struct and then just compile that file inside the console using the `c` function -> `c("my_file.ex")` and use that function to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but you can pass the script using the `iex --dot-iex script.exs`. See [The .iex.exs file](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-the-iex-exs-file).

```
$ iex --dot-iex script.exs
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Interactive Elixir (1.9.1) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> person
%{age: 45, name: "Bob"}
```

> How do I retrieve Bob's age after I compile the script with `elixir script.exs`?

Not sure what you mean here. After you run the script, the script has finished, so there's no way to retrieve any of the values (unless the script returns or sets the environment).

Comment: I meant to use the Map “interactively”, according to my needs,  after Elixir loads it. Thus avoiding using a real database. (With all its pluses and minuses, of course). I hope this is clearer now

Comment: It's still pretty unclear what you're asking. If you just want to get Bob's age in IEx, use this solution, then try your `person[:age]` in IEx (`person.age` should also work). Or are you saying you want to do something like this in an Elixir project you can use from one of your modules?

Comment: Just the 1st case you suggested, but after the script is loaded, person[:age] gave me an error, as I wrote. That’s why I asked the question.

Comment: In other words, I’d like to use interactively an already written Map from a script, not having to re-write the Map each time.

Comment: Yes, it gives me an error: undefined function person/0

Comment: It sounds like you've not read the first sentence of this answer, because that does what you want. :-)

Comment: Sure, my fault. I had everything in a module, and  it didn’t work. I deleted the module, and now it works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: What does the —dot-iex actually do?

Comment: That information is in the official docs linked from the second sentence. ;-)